# Calling and Embed Resource thru a Process on Button Click

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, visual-studio-2012, cmd

So I have added resources to my solution (VS2012 (C#)). I have set them to `embedded`.

I have written a process:

```
private void Run_CMD(string arguments);
{
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        process.Start();
}
```

I have a Menubox and one of the selections runs the process plus its arguments

```
Run_CMD(Argument Here);
```

I have other scripts that use the CMD process and work but the one I am trying to run references a XML file to load a wireless profile.

The command is

```
/k netsh wlan add profile filename=atoksvli.xml user=all & sc config Wlansvc start= Auto & net Start Wlansvc
```

And this command in a Bat file with the xml in the same directory works running it but I want to add it to my WPF so when I select the menu option and hit the run button to activate the process it will pull the profile from the xml that I have added as a resource.

I have looked at other code that talk about loading the embedded resources at compile or run but none seem to work for me.  Please give me some clues as what I need to do to keep my code the same so selecting a menu item then hit run will activate it and the embedded resource that it needs to use to load the profile.

Thanks for any help and advice,

tmitcham

Comment: Um, the root of your problem is that you can't get some embedded XML?  Why don't you post the code that is supposed to be getting the XML?  It is possible I have misunderstood, but it seems like everything you have posted here is just the noise surrounding the real problem.

Comment: /k netsh wlan add profile filename=atoksvli.xml user=all & sc config Wlansvc start= Auto & net Start Wlansvc is the argument that will be in the () after Run_CMD that activates that process.  I have tried diffrent code about loading embed resources using Assembly and System.IO, System.Reflection but nothing seems to work at loading the embed resource so the argument would hit the Temp folder which I am assuming is where everything is loaded when the WPF is run. Other then this information I have no idea where to even start. (Thanks for the Comment)

Comment: A BAT file will use the environmental variables while Process will not.  So you need to include the full pathname of netsh and atoksvli.xml

Comment: Since I am trying to embed the xml as a resource that will be compiled and finalized into an exe in the end will I still need to include the full path to the xml.  I trying to keep the program from trying to find external files to run its functions and use internal resources.  Plus if the file was moved from the path layed out in the code after install then the program wouldn't work right???? (Thanks for the Comment)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to export the resource to a directory then run the argument for the cmd process and point to the file location that is set in the program and then when the program exits it cleans up all directory's and files created.

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))//Does Directory Exist if so then copy and run file
                {
                    String myfile = Properties.Resources.ATOKSVLI;
                    File.WriteAllText (@"C:\SD\\ATOKSVLI.xml", myfile);
                    Run_CMD("/k netsh wlan add profile filename=atoksvli.xml user=all & sc config Wlansvc start= Auto & net Start Wlansvc ");
                }
            else //Create directory then copy file and run
                {
                    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    String myfile = Properties.Resources.ATOKSVLI;
                    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\SD\\ATOKSVLI.xml", myfile);
                    Run_CMD("/k netsh wlan add profile filename=atoksvli.xml user=all & sc config Wlansvc start= Auto & net Start Wlansvc ");
                }
```

Thanks for all the great comments and advice it got me think about what to ask and where to look.